# Error getting messages from JMS Queue

Tags: java, queue, jms, javax

I get a JMS Queue (JAVAX.JMS) I stablish connection through:

```
jmsConnect = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
jmsSession = jmsConnect.createQueueSession(true,     jmsSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
jmsConnect.start();
connection = queueConnectionFactory.createConnection();
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
connection.start();
```

I try to get queued messages with this function:

```
QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(Queue);
Enumeration e = browser.getEnumeration();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
e.nextElement();
cont++;
}
browser.close();
browser = null;
```

There are at least 1 queued messages, but when the function try to get the total of queued messages, always return 0, some idea of what could be happen?

Comment: How do you know that there are messages in the queue ? Do you have any console to the MQ to view them ?

Comment: Because I see it in JBoss administrative console, my Queue has 1 message queued, the queue is setting as durable, but when I try to monitoring that queue with code, the answer is always 0, the hasMoreElements method always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have an expired message on the queue. You will still find the messages are in the enqueued count , however when you try to read the message or in your case browse it may not be made available to your application. An example in AMQ turns [this up](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-queue.html)

Comment: HI! The queue is setting as durable the message never get lost, I have a listener to reestablish communication, and when I turn it on the message queued is received